# Block sum for degenerate affine Hecke algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras, affine-hecke-algebras

The *degenerate affine Hecke algebra* $H_k$ over a field $F$ is the algebra with generators $s_1,\ldots,s_{k-1}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, subject to the following relations:

- $s_is_js_i=s_js_is_j$ for $i=j\pm 1$
- $s_is_j=s_js_i$ for $i\neq j\pm 1$
- $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$ for all $i,j$
- $x_{i+1}s_i=s_ix_i +1$ for all $i\leq k-1$
- $x_js_i=s_ix_j$ for $j\neq i,i+1$.

This means that $s_1,\ldots,s_{k-1}$ generate a copy of the group algebra $FS_k$ of the symmetric group $S_k$, and that $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ generate a copy of the polynomial algebra $F[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$.  Moreover there is a quotient map $H_k\twoheadrightarrow FS_k$ sending $x_1$ to $0$.

> **Question 1:** Just as there is a *block sum* $FS_j\otimes FS_k\to FS_{j+k}$, is there also a *block sum* $H_j\otimes H_k\to H_{j+k}$?  If so, what is the effect of this map on the generators $x_i$ in the second factor $H_k$?

> **Question 2:** If the answer to Question 1 is "yes", then is there also a block sum for the degenerate cyclotomic Hecke algebras $H_k^\Lambda$?